# Как сохранить элементы добавленные с помощью createElement() прямо в html коде?

Tags: javascript, html

В моем html коде есть div-ы с айди от 1 до 3, и когда в форме я выбираю номер формы, там появляются данные с формы, но после перезагрузки страницы они конечно пропадают, и вот у меня вопрос: как их сохранить?

```js
function add_element() {
  var parent = document.getElementById('h4');
  var nick = document.createElement('h4');
  nick.innerHTML = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
  var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
  var elemdiv = document.createElement('p');
  elemdiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById('msg').value;
  if (document.getElementById('number').value == '1') {
    n1.append(nick);
    n1.append(dateTime);
    n1.append(elemdiv);
  } else if (document.getElementById('number').value == '2') {
    n2.append(nick);
    n2.append(dateTime);
    n2.append(elemdiv);
  } else if (document.getElementById('number').value == '3') {
    n3.append(nick);
    n3.append(dateTime);
    n3.append(elemdiv);

    else {
      alert('Null!')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно через
local storage
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('nick', nick);
localStorage.getItem('nick');
```

Comment: Как юзать это в коде?